# R studio - lwd argument does not work in lines() function

Tags: r

I recently studied how to draw flight route between two destinations.

I learned the code from here
https://www.gis-blog.com/flight-connection-map-with-r/?unapproved=5101&moderation-hash=f14c3f9e10eb5d9e983e2339bdcf05c2#comment-5101

In the blog, the map looks like this. As you can see  the lines in the sample picture in very thin and transparent.

[image]

I did exactly what it asked me to do and but when I plot the map it looks like that. As you can see lines in the map I generated is very thick

[image]

Even i tried to change the lwd value, i did not find any difference, i am confused on why this happened. Any one has any clue on this?

This is my code:

```
for (i in (1:dim(usairports)[1])) { 
  inter <- gcIntermediate(c(jfk$lon[1], jfk$lat[1]), c(usairports$lon[i], usairports$lat[i]), n=200)
  lines(inter, lwd=0.000001, col="turquoise2")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Trying adding transparency, e.g. change `col` in `lines` to `col = rgb(0, 0.895, 0.930, alpha = 0.5)`? The RGB values [should correspond to `turquoise2`](https://www.color-hex.com/color/00e5ee).

Comment: I think this might have something to do with the really bad anti-aliasing on Windows. I get the same result with thick lines if I just generate the plot (with `lwd = 0.1` as in the original blog), but if I use `png(..., type = 'cairo')` I get the nice thin lines.

Comment: @Marius   Hi Marius, many thanks for your advice! How and where should I use png()? I never used this function before. Thanks heaps!!!

Comment: Look at the help page `?png`, particularly the examples at the end: you have to use `png(..., type = 'cairo')` before you start plotting, then do all your plotting, then call `dev.off()` at the end to return the plotting system to normal.

Comment: @Marius many thanks for your help, I will have a look help page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R on Windows has notoriously bad aliasing by default in its plots, meaning you see very "jagged" lines. Using the Cairo plotting system tends to give much better results, e.g.:

```
png("airport.png", type = "cairo")

map("world", regions=c("usa"), fill=T, col="grey8", bg="grey15", ylim=c(21.0,50.0), xlim=c(-130.0,-65.0))
#overlay airports
points(usairports$lon,usairports$lat, pch=3, cex=0.1, col="chocolate1")

for (i in (1:dim(usairports)[1])) { 
    inter <- gcIntermediate(c(jfk$lon[1], jfk$lat[1]), c(usairports$lon[i], usairports$lat[i]), n=200)
    lines(inter, lwd=0.1, col="turquoise2")    
}

dev.off()
```

Comment: many thanks for your help. I tried your method and it worked!